# Programatically moving OneDrive files between online and offline

Tags: c#, .net, file, attributes, onedrive

I've been asked to write a small task tray application that will help with managing users local drive space - to be more specific, to take advantage of OneDrive's Smart File capability so that files appear offline when not.

The ask is to monitor/check all the files in the users OneDrive folder and if they have not been updated in the last 30 days, then make them "online only".

In File Explorer users can right click on files and folders and select "make online only", but the aim is to do this automatically.

I'm hoping there is an attribute or flag I can set in the File or FileInfo objects in C# .Net that will then trigger the sync agent to do the necessary.

Is this possible?

Cheers,

Roy

Answer (score 6):

The OneDrive's 'Always keep on this device' menu sets the `Pinned` file attribute. The 'Free up space' menu sets the `Unpinned` file system attribute:

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_PINNED 0x00080000

FILE_ATTRIBUTE_UNPINNED 0x00100000
```

I guess OneDrive monitors these attributes and triggers hydration/dehydration if you change them.

You can also trigger hydration by calling the [CfHydratePlaceholder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfhydrateplaceholder) Windows API. You can dehydrate by calling [CfUpdatePlaceholder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfupdateplaceholder).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't invest time in such a feature given that Windows 10 currently lacks smart files, and it's probably that that majority of users who are currently on Windows 8.1 will upgrade.